# On primes at equidistant on both sides of a given odd number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

One of my teachers made the following observation (it might be a known one):

For any number $n\geq 5$, there exists a $d$ such that $n-d$ and $n+d$ are primes and we were clueless at the beginning how to proceed. We tried attacking odd numbers first. So far the following is the progress. We just landed on an equivalent problem, a simple observation. We realised that it is enough to prove the following:

*If $n$ is an odd number and if $p_1, \dots, p_k$ are all odd primes less than $n$, then one of the numbers $2n-p_1, \dots, 2n-p_k$ is a prime.*

We don't know the truthfulness of the above statement. But we made two observations: the proof of above immediately implies Bertrand's postulate for $n$ odd and Goldbach's conjecture for numbers of the form $2n$, where $n$ is odd.

I have not done enough literature survey in this regard. Any help to the references (or an independent proof for the above italicized statement) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the original conjecture of your teacher immediately implies Goldbach for every even number $\geq 10$. On the other hand if Goldbach is true then for any even number $2n$ there are primes $p \leqslant q$ with $p+q=2n$, so the conjecture holds with $d=(q-p)/2$. So it's equivalent to Goldbach.

Comment: I am simply wondering is there a way the italicised statement could be proved independently.

Comment: @YathirajSharma as I read from Matthew Towers' comment, it can't be done unless the Goldbach conjecture is proven true.

Comment: I understand...